# The normalizer of a proper sub-algebra properly contains the sub-algebra in a nilpotent Lie algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

So I am just making my way into the theory of Lie Algebras. The question at hand comes from page 14 of Humphreys, *Introduction to Lie Algebra and Representation Theory*.

> Given a finite dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra $L$, and a proper sub-algebra $K$ of $L$, prove that the normalizer of $K$ properly contains $K$.

I keep trying to use Engel's theorem, but I have only been able to show there is a vector such that $[v\ K]$ is in the center, which much be in $K$. Though the condition for $v$ was only that it is in $L$.

A proof or anything else would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Here is one way: Split into two cases. Note that the center of $L$ will normalize $K$, so if $K$ does not contain the center, you are done. If $K$ does contain the center, it corresponds to a subalgebra of $L/Z(L)$ which has strictly smaller dimension than $L$. Induction.

Comment: Ah, the untangeable bravdo of induction. Thank you, I hadn't thought of that. I wonder, does the proposition hold in infinite dimensional spaces?

Comment: I am not actually sure in the infinite-dimensional case. My guess would be that it still holds, but I am not sure.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  Won't your proof work for infinite dimensional Lie algebras if you recast it as an induction on the ascending central series (which, if I correctly understand the definitions, still has to be finite in a nilpotent algebra), instead of an induction on dimension?

Comment: I think the last name of the cited book's author is not "Humphrey" but "Humphreys".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, you are right. The proof carries over directly if one looks at the length of the central series instead of the dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my comment as an answer:

We do this by induction on the length of the ascending central series (which is finite since $L$ is nilpotent).

If $K$ does not contain $Z(L)$ then we are done, as clearly $Z(L)$ normalizes $K$. So we assume that $Z(L)\subseteq K$ and look at the quotient $L/Z(L)$ which is nilpotent and has a shorter ascending central series than $L$.

$K$ corresponds to a subalgebra $\overline{K}$ of $L/Z(L)$ since $Z(L)\subseteq K$, and by induction, the normalizer of $\overline{K}$ strictly contains $\overline{K}$. But anything in the preimage of this normalizer in $L$ will normalize $K$, and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you need Engel's theorem.

Since $K$ is a proper subalgebra of $L$, we have $L/K$ nontrivial. Then consider the adjoint action of $K$ on $L/K$. By Engel's theorem, there exists an element $\bar{x} \neq \bar{0}$ such that ad$y.\bar{x} \neq \bar{0}$. It means that there exists element $x \notin K$ such that $[y,x]\notin K$ for all $y \in K$. Hence we find such element $x\in N_L(K)$ but $x\notin K$.

Done.

Comment: This doesn't work in the infinite dimensional case.